# Can't reach port 9050

Tags: raspbian, linux, troubleshooting

I have a problem with tor (this version and also 0.2.7.*). After compilation, with and without installation afterwards, I can'treach port 9050. I would like to see with arm what's going on but it doesn`t work.

```
blabla@Raspb:~$ sudo -u debian-tor arm
Connection refused. Is the ControlPort enabled?
```

When I do this it won`t work either.

```
blabla@Raspb:~$ sudo -u debian-tor arm -i 127.0.0.1:9050
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TorCtl/TorCtl.py", line 645, in _loop
    isEvent, reply = self._read_reply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TorCtl/TorCtl.py", line 820, in _read_reply
    raise ProtocolError("Badly formatted reply line: unknown type %r"%tp)
ProtocolError: Badly formatted reply line: unknown type 'P'
```

But tor binds the port

```
blabla@Raspb:~$ sudo netstat -tulpan | grep "9050"
[sudo] password for torpi: 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17247/tor
```

I`ve search many things but still got no solution. 
My torrc works fine. 
I have to say on the beginning tor can't bind port 80 and 443. After I did this it worked.

```
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/local/bin/tor
```

Is their relation compared to port 9050?
When I install tor from the repositories all worked fine.
Hope you can help me.

Thanx!